# Можно ли создать прямую ссылку onion на файл?

Tags: файлы, ссылки, tor, onion

Я знаю что можно создать ссылку на какой то текст просто проксируя порт сетью Тор. Но у меня встал вопрос можно но ли передать файл так же анонимно по сети Тор ? На обоих устройствах сеть установлена.